# Как back-end узнаёт о Google-авторизации в Android-приложении?

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, авторизация

Я разрабатываю серверную часть приложения на Rails.
Front-end — мобильное приложение на Android / iOS.

Задача — в приложении должна быть возможность входить через Google-аккаунт. Но я не понимаю, как всё это должно взаимодействовать.
Даже если пользователь авторизуется именно в приложении, как back-end об этом узнает?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Делается это так:

1. На клиенте каким-то образом (через SDK соц.сети или через браузер (в т.ч. встроенный в приложение)) юзер авторизуется в вашем приложении. Под последним имеется в виду набор из сгенерированных соц.сетью ключей, которые надо указывать при обращении к API оной. В случае гугла оно, вроде, и не нужно.
2. После авторизации, в зависимости от соц.сети и всяких разных условий (секурность там всякая etc) с клиента на ваш сервер шлётся ID юзера (случай гугла), `authCode` или `accessToken`.
3. В зависимости от того, что именно клиент вам присылает надо или валидировать ID, или обменять `authCode` на `accessToken`. Если присылается сразу `accessToken` то переходим к след. пункту.
4. Теперь у вас есть все возможности получения всех возможных (разрешённых юзером) данных юзера. Либо как в случае с гуглом, после проверки присланного ID вы получаете объект юзера и делаете с ним что хотите (в БД кладёте, например или обновляете дату его последнего посещения) или, имея токен запращиваете его данные из API соц. сети.

Вот гугловая дока по поводу сервера:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

Там написано, что есть либы под `JAVA`, `NODE.JS`, `PHP`, `PYTHON`